# How to use the following data to populate the tableVIew cells?

Tags: ios, swift, scope

I am a beginner to iOS development and I am working on a weather app. I am trying to find any solution to the following problem for 3 days now but no clues. So please help me on this.

The problem is How do I use the data fetched from the code below to populate the tableViewCells ?

```
//TODO: get 3 day forecast
func getWeather() {
    let params: [String:String] = ["q": place!, "appid": APP_ID]
    Alamofire.request(WEATHER_URL ,method: .get, parameters: params).responseJSON { (response) in
        let result = JSON(response.result.value!)
        print(result)
    }
}

func updateTable( json: JSON) {
    print(json["list"].count)
    for i in 0...json.count - 1 {
        self.weatherObject.date = json["list"][i]["dt_txt"].stringValue
        self.weatherObject.temp = json["list"][i]["main"]["temp"].intValue
        self.weatherObject.weather = json["list"][i]["weather"][0]["main"].stringValue
        print(weatherObject.date)
        forecastDate.append(weatherObject.date)
        forecastTemp.append(weatherObject.temp)
        forecastWeather.append(weatherObject.weather)
        print(forecastDate[i])
        print(forecastTemp[i])
        print(forecastWeather[i])
    }
}
```

`weatherObject` is an object of weather class that I have created to  structure the weather data.

This is really very confusing since whenever I try to pass the arrays that are: forecastWeather, forecastDate, forecastTemp into tableView delegate and datasource methods , there are actually no values in there.
Is there any way to sort out this coding problem?

Comment: Do not post pictures of code. Please [edit] your question and replace the image with the actual code, as text. Pictures can't be searched or referenced, they are harder to read, and they are more difficult to put into your question.

Comment: ok, sorry for the inconvenience. This is the very first question I have asked here.

Comment: That's fine, just [edit] your question as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the result into array of structs or classes in your UIViewController. Then implement the following methods:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return yourArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "providerCell", for: indexPath) as! YourTableViewCell
    // set your data to cell

    return cell
}
```

In your ViewController, when the data download is completed call `tableView.reloadData()`.

I recommend you to find some tutorial for example https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/uikit/uitableviewcontroller/.